# How do you use the ionic CLI to debug a Meteor app?

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

I have an app created by the ionic CLI that uses the angular meteor packages. It's working great with "ionic serve".  But, how do I tell the app where to find the  server when I "ionic run android" to test and debug.

To clarify, I'm looking for the Ionic CLI equivalent to:

meteor run android-device --mobile-server my_app_name.meteor.com

So far, the best I can do is the edit the ionic index.html to do something like:

```
// IP for USB connected phone
SERVER_URL = "http://92.168.99.1:3000/";  // Changes a lot. Run ipconfig. Look for Virtual Box???
window.__meteor_runtime_config__ = {DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL: SERVER_URL};
console.log("Server URL: " + SERVER_URL)
```

Comment: if(Meteor.server){//If it is the server do this}... And if you want client if(Meteor.client){//If it is the client do this...}